# Formatting/adding a continuous border around a vb6 datareport

Tags: vb6

I am designing a report in vb6 using datareport. But i am having an issue with formatting.
I have drawn line in Detail section(section 1) and  there is Page footer below that. But when I execute the Report the Line is not completely connected to Pagefooter.

This is my Report format..
[image]

Comment: @Charles Why'd you remove the datareport tag? I know nothing else is tagged using it but the question is still specifically about the datareport functionality.

Comment: @Deanna, you hit the nail on the head: when the tag was created, whoever did so did not make the effort to find other questions to which it could apply.  Tags with a single question aren't helpful and tend to get removed, either by humans or by an automated process that runs every once in a while.

Comment: there is no tag named datareport and i cant create a new one

Comment: guyz give me the solution. plzz